# My website social media icons is not reflecting mobile devices,

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My website social media icons is not reflecting mobile devices, Here is the link, I hosted in web server, please check it. http://lotusvalue.com/

```
<div class="nav-top">
<div class="w3-contact">
<a> <span class="fa fa-volume-control-phone" aria-hidden="true"> </span>+91 7676730000
</a>
<a href="mailto:abcd@yoursite.com"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true" ></span>info@lotusvaluedevelopers.com</a>
</div>
<div class="w3-socials">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/lotusvaluerealestate/" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://twitter.com/lotus_value" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  .w3-contact a {
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }
    .w3-contact {
        padding: 10px 0px;
            font-size: 14px;
    }
    .w3-socials {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .w3-socials ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CDN in style tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and

`@media screen and (max-width: 480px){` 
`.w3-socials {  display: inline-block; }`

Comment: Please check, I have uploaded the link in web server , it is not reflecting. http://lotusvalue.com/

Comment: Have you tested, It is not reflecting and also, it hides in laptop screen and not showing  nothing  in mobile screen, please cross check

Comment: use @media screen and (max-width: 480px){ 
.w3-socials {  display: inline-block; }

Comment: for fb i have used  this class <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> and for twitter i have used <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>, now i want to know , linked in span class, which funciton i want to use, see the url

Comment: I have taken form net, just to ensure with you i have asked, <span class="fa fa-linkedin"> thanks for your valuable answer and timely support